# Solve nested conditional (error) levels in php

Tags: php, nested, conditional-statements

I am trying to solve nested conditional levels in php related to error handling.

I already read some questions and answers here, e.g. for flatteing things.

But... Imagine something a function like

```
function my_function() {

    // 1. Doing things here
    // ...


    // 2. Handle something with text here
    $foo = 'some text ...';

    $foo = function_a($foo); // Handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error

    $foo = function_b($foo); // Also handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error

    // Final functions doing things with the text


    // 3. Doing other things here

    return TRUE;

}
```

To do things right, I should do error handling:

```
function my_function() {

    // 1. Doing things here
    // ...


    // 2. Handle something with text here
    $foo = 'some text ...';

    $foo = function_a($foo); // Handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
    if (FALSE === $foo) {
        // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
    }

    $foo = function_b($foo); // Also handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
    if (FALSE === $foo) {
        // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
    }

    // Final functions doing things with the text


    // 3. Doing other things here

    return TRUE;

}
```

Maybe you already see my problem: Handling the errors would need me to nest the `if`s

```
    $foo = function_a($foo); // Handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
    if (FALSE === $foo) {
        // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
    }
    else {
        $foo = function_b($foo); // Also handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
        if (FALSE === $foo) {
            // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
        }
        else {
            // Final functions doing things with the text
        }
    }
```

to do the final functions because returning from the function is NOT an option (step 3 should be executed independent from what in 2. happend).

Do you have any idea how to "flatten" these kind of nested conditionals?

Comment: Please tell more detail

Comment: If you already have a working code, and just need optimization, you can ask it in [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You can change up the code design a bit and just return early from your function:

```
function my_function() {  
    $foo = function_a($foo); // Handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
    if (FALSE === $foo) {
        // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
        return FALSE;
    }

    $foo = function_b($foo); // Also handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
    if (FALSE === $foo) {
        // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Final functions doing things with the text
    return TRUE;
}

function outer_function() {
    $result = my_function()

    // 3. Doing other things here

    // Do things with $result
}
```

---

Another way to handle this is to use a [`try`-`catch`-`finally`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block.

```
function my_function() {  
    try {
        $foo = function_a($foo); // Handling the text, doing something, returning FALSE in case of error
        if (FALSE === $foo) { throw new Exception('function_a failed'); }

        $foo = function_b($foo); // Also handling the text, doing something, 
        if (FALSE === $foo) { throw new Exception('function_b failed'); }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle error, e.g. skip to next flow after code block
        // echo error messages
        return FALSE;
    } finally {
        // Final functions doing things with the text whether successful or not
    }
    // 3. Doing other things here if all successful
    return TRUE;
}
```

I like the 2nd way better, cause it feels cleaner, and the `finally` statement will execute *before* returning `FALSE` if there's an error. You could avoid the `throw` statements if your inner functions raise exceptions on their own and consolidate all the error handling.

Comment: See my notice to step 3 which should be executed even if the block in 2. fails

Comment: @SchubiDuah Sorry, I missed that. You can easily take care of that in an outer function, with this set up.

Comment: The problem with "finally" is: It's executed whether there was an exception or not. And my "problem" was to have a kind of linear "do something - if ok: goon - do something else - if ok: goon - ... - do something a the end of 2. if EVERYTHING before was ok"

Comment: @SchubiDuah That's what the `catch` statement is for, you "do something if not ok" in there. I don't know what sort of code you would put in there. In my experience, it's usually something that may use common code, so it's easier to keep those types of statements together and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @SchubiDuah Is the downvote still necessary? If the update solution has helped you, please accept the answer.